# How do I make the number "0" display in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a decimal column that contains percentages.  I'm converting these so that they display as their whole `#` counterparts.  For example, if a value is `0.35` in the database, I'm displaying it as `35` in the textbox.  However, some of the values are `0.00`, but don't display in the textbox as `0`.  In fact, nothing shows up at all.

What would be the proper `ToString()` format to use to achieve my desired result?

Comment: 0.ToSring() returns "0", you sure it's not a nullable int with no value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `.ToString("N0")` or am I missing something?

Comment: No this worked great.  I can't believe I overlooked that.  Haha thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the template below:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);
```

See http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Thus, you multiply by 100 and display without decimal places. It should work well

Comment: Multiplying 0 by a 100 would surely cause problems?

Comment: Why use `String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0)` when you can use `123.0.ToString("0.00")`?